# Pandas and SQLAlchemy: df.to_sql() with SQLAlchemy 2.0 future=True throws an error when using a connection from engine.begin()

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I tried to upsert a table in MS SQL Server from a pandas DataFrame.

As I understand it, it's a two step process:

- do a pandas df.to_sql() into a temp table
- execute a magic sql to merger the temp table in the existing final table

this works, but only if i set future=False in the create_engine call.

```py
   self.engine = create_engine(self.url, echo=True, future=False)
  with self.engine.begin() as conn:
            df.to_sql("#update_table", conn, if_exists="append", index=False)
            # merge...
            sql = f"""\
            -- magic sql
            """
            result = conn.execute(text(sql)).fetchone()
```

When using `future=True` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/dc_uk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1340, in insert_records
    table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/dc_uk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 959, in insert
    with self.pd_sql.run_transaction() as conn:
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/dc_uk/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/dc_uk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1416, in run_transaction
    with self.connectable.begin() as tx:
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/dc_uk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/future/engine.py", line 144, in begin
    return super(Connection, self).begin()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/dc_uk/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 766, in begin
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This connection has already initialized a SQLAlchemy Transaction() object via begin() or autobegin; can't call begin() here unless rollback() or commit() is called first.
```

It seems like something in pandas can't deal (yet) with the changes in SA2. :(

There are some questions about SQLAlchemy 2.0 from earlier this year but all of them are closed.

My Question:
Anything i did wrong? or is that still an open issue...?

PS:
This is on a mac, python 3.9.7, pandas 1.3.4, and SQLAlchemy 1.4.27.

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs "future" causes a transaction to start automatically, so you don't call `.begin()`.

eg

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(...)
    conn.execute(...)
    conn.commit()

    conn.execute(...)
    conn.execute(...)
    conn.commit()
```

[method sqlalchemy.future.Connection.begin()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/future.html#sqlalchemy.future.Connection.begin)

Comment: that gives a new error: `File "/Users/ar/src/fuelminr/dc_uk_gold/src/DataFactory/scores.py", line 301, in scores_upsert
    with self.engine as conn:
AttributeError: __enter__`... :/

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in pandas. See [this issue comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40686#issuecomment-872031119).

Rather than setting `future=False`, I replaced the call to `to_sql` with `to_dict` + SQL query.

(I'm using postgresql and appending doesn't take a temp table.)

```py
        data_dict = data_df.reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")

        query = (
            sqla.dialects.postgresql.insert(table)
            .values(data_dict)
            .on_conflict_do_nothing()
        )
        db.session.execute(query)
        db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the pandas version

```
pip install pandas==1.4.1
```